# How to simulate a wave equation

Tags: javascript, math, simulation

I've been recently trying to simulate a wave equation in [p5.js](https://p5js.org/es/reference/).

My aproach is to plot a bunch of points with `(x, y)` coordinates. I've used the wave equation for obtaining the movement of those particles.

This is my numerical integration method:

```js
var pos     = this.masses[i].pos
var nextPos = this.masses[i + 1].pos
var lastPos = this.masses[i - 1].pos

var vel = this.masses[i].vel, acc = this.masses[i].acc // for simplicity

acc.x = 0
acc.y = c * c * ((nextPos.y - 2*pos.y + lastPos.y)) / d2x

vel.x += acc.x * dt
vel.y += acc.y * dt

pos.x += vel.x * dt
pos.y += vel.y * dt
```

My acceleration is defined as the second derivative with respect to x times the speed of the wave squared, as shown [here](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/5b0e6dbd1c6ae8ebbe0680b849687981bfb22c3a).

So I convert my equation from this:

```
(d²u/dt²) = c² (d²u/dx²)
```

Into a discrete equation like this (where `u`, represents the position of one particle and `c` the propagation speed of the waves):

```js
d2u = u(x + 2h, t) - 2*u(x + h, t) + u(x, t)
d2t = 1e-5 // small step
acc = c * c * (d2u / d2t)
```

But my result is quite strange:
[image: my wave]

As you can see, the wave grows, when the expected result was something like this:

[image: expected wave]

What I'm doing wrong? Someone could help me?
Thanks :)

Comment: You should check out `The Coding Train`, he has a lot of video on p5.js as he's one of the main contributors. [Additive waves video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=okfZRl4Xw-c)

Comment: You need to get a book on numerical analysis, and one with concrete code examples :-) I wonder which one is the best. But almost sure there are a few out there. I don't know the answer to your problem, but would be fun to investigate.

Comment: (some solvers are known to diverge under certain circumstances, bounding that is kind of the main goal of numerical analysis)